# Django PostgreSQL DatabaseError: relation "categories" does not exist

Tags: django

I am working on a Django app. Initially I was using MySQL for database. Then, I needed to deploy a demo app on heroku, which uses PostgreSQL.

I am getting an error in heroku when I try to create an object, even from shell.

This is what I am trying to do:

```
>> from store.models import Product, Category
>> cat = Category()
>> cat.name = 'books'
>> cat.description = 'books'
>> cat.slug = 'books'
>> cat.save()
```

I get the following error:

```
......
DatabaseError: relation "categories" does not exist
```

Here's my Category and Product models

```
class Category(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  description = models.TextField()
  slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Product(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
  description = models.TextField()
  price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
  slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)
  categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

It works very well with MySQL, but not with PostgreSQL.

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Pretty straight-forward. For whatever reason, that field isn't actually on your database table. Run `python manage.py dbshell` and then enter `\d+ yourapp_product` at the prompt to see what the current state is.

Answer (score 6):

You need to run syncdb in heroku as well so it installs your app and models.

```
heroku run python manage.py syncdb
```

If you made changes to your schema and you are using south then:

```
heroku run python manage.py schemamigration appname --auto
```