# Why is Django ManyToManyField causing admin interface to crash? Why is no through table being created?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Why is this line

```
users_favorited_by = models.ManyToManyField('auth.User')
```

or this one, which causes the same error:

```
users_favorited_by = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

in this model

```
class Album(models.Model):
    OFFICIALITY = (
        ('J', 'Major studio release'),
        ('I', 'Non-major official release'),
        ('U', 'Unofficial'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, default="", null=True, blank=True)
    pub_date = models.DateField('release date')
    officiality = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=OFFICIALITY)
    is_concert = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    main_info_url = models.URLField(blank=False)
    thumbnail = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name, blank=True, null=True)

    #virtual field to skip over the through table.
    songs = models.ManyToManyField("Song", through="AlbumSong")

    users_favorited_by = models.ManyToManyField('auth.User')

    #Alternative to Meta.ordering [2/2]:
    #objects = AlbumAscPubDateManager()


    def __str__(self):
        return  self.title

    class Meta:
        #Default ordering is by release date, ascending.
        ordering = ['pub_date']
```

resulting in this error in the admin interface, when clicking on a specific album?

```
ProgrammingError at /admin/billyjoel/album/1/
relation "billyjoel_album_users_favorited_by" does not exist
LINE 1: ...LECT "auth_user"."id" FROM "auth_user" INNER JOIN "billyjoel...
                                                         ^
```

The admin interface works fine, *until* you click on an album to see its detail.

Comment that `ManyToManyField` out, run `makemigrations` then `migrate`, and the admin interface works fine--you can see the album's detail.

According to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294756/django-postgresql-databaseerror-relation-categories-does-not-exist#comment14860621_11294756), the error implies that the column does not exist in the database.

So why, when ***un***-commenting out the `ManyToManyField` (and again running `makemigrations` then `migrate`), is no database table being created? As in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25433871/where-how-is-django-manytomanyfield-represented-in-the-database), the first two answerers both state that an automatically-created through table should be made. So where is it?

```
jdb=# \dt public.*
                  List of relations
 Schema |            Name            | Type  | Owner
--------+----------------------------+-------+--------
 public | auth_group                 | table | pguser
 public | auth_group_permissions     | table | pguser
 public | auth_permission            | table | pguser
 public | auth_user                  | table | pguser
 public | auth_user_groups           | table | pguser
 public | auth_user_user_permissions | table | pguser
 public | billyjoel_album            | table | pguser
 public | billyjoel_albumsong        | table | pguser
 public | billyjoel_song             | table | pguser
 public | django_admin_log           | table | pguser
 public | django_content_type        | table | pguser
 public | django_migrations          | table | pguser
 public | django_session             | table | pguser
(13 rows)
```

---

Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8001/admin/billyjoel/album/1/

Django Version: 1.7c2
Python Version: 3.4.0
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'billyjoel')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  546.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  105.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  52.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  204.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in change_view
  1416.         return self.changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
File "/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  29.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  105.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  25.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
File "/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py" in inner
  394.                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changeform_view
  1378.                 form = ModelForm(instance=obj)
File "/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in __init__
  319.             object_data = model_to_dict(instance, opts.fields, opts.exclude)
File "/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in model_to_dict
  149.                     data[f.name] = list(qs.values_list('pk', flat=True))
File "/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__
  141.         self._fetch_all()
File "/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
  964.             self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
File "/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in iterator
  1200.             for row in self.query.get_compiler(self.db).results_iter():
File "/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in results_iter
  699.         for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
File "/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  785.             cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  81.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
File "/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  94.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/six.py" in reraise
  549.             raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /admin/billyjoel/album/1/
Exception Value: relation "billyjoel_album_users_favorited_by" does not exist
LINE 1: ...LECT "auth_user"."id" FROM "auth_user" INNER JOIN "billyjoel...
                                                             ^
```

Comment: I think your database is in an inconsistent state through all this commenting/migrating/uncommenting. Try dropping your db completely, deleting your migration files, and running makemigrations and migrate again.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yup. Thanks. Thank goodness I created a script for all my initial data inserts!!! Now back to the previous question... (Consider writing it up as an answer so I can give you credit.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your database is in an inconsistent state through all this commenting/migrating/uncommenting. Try dropping your db completely, deleting your migration files, and running makemigrations and migrate again.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I executed @DanielRoseman's advice, using two shells to my Ubuntu machine, both starting in the "main" user's command prompt:

1. First, delete all `"000*"` files from `/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test/billyjoel/migrations` and `/home/jeffy/django_files/django_test/billyjoel/migrations/__pycache__`
2. Shell one

   1. `sudo su - postgres`
   2. postgres command prompt:

      1. `dropdb django_test_db`
      2. `createdb django_test_db`
      3. `psql django_test_db`
      4. `\dt public.*`          (should display *no* tables)
3. Shell two

   1. `source /home/jeffy/django_files/django_test_venv/bin/activate`
   2. `cd /home/jeffy/django_files/django_test`  (the directory containing `manage.py`)
   3. `python manage.py makemigrations`
   4. `python manage.py migrate`
4. Shell one:

   1. Verify it worked with

      1. `psql django_test_db`
      2. `\dt public.*`            (should display your Django tables)